# MiKTeX Path refresh FNDB

Tags: miktex, folders

I have several cls files and macros in a folder that is set as a root directory for MikTeX in Windows (The files are in `C:/localtexmf/tex/latex/Macros` and the root directory is set as `C:/localtexmf`). However, whenever I update any of the files in this folder, or add new cls files, I need to run the update FNDB again for LaTeX (TeXMaker) to recognize the changes. On other operating systems (Ubuntu and Mac) once the folder is specified within the tree I did not need to run an update every time. Is this not the case for Windows?

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: Not needing to hash the local tree in TeX Live has been the case for a few years but not always. It's down to Christian Schenk to define how MiKTeX works: you can always use TeX Live on Windows if you prefer it's approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasn't aware of TeX Live so may try this out instead.

Comment: As far as I experienced it, you need to update FNDB when you _add_ new files, not when you update them.

Comment: @Bernard: Or when files are removed. So, a fndb update is necessary, when there is some change in file structure.

Comment: @JosephWright: This is the only possible answer in the moment in my eyes, perhaps with small additions of Bernard and me.

Comment: @Speravir: You're right, but 'twas implicit. What's funny with MiKTeX Settings interface is that you can do many things with it, but launching updmap.exe was not provided. It should be, as a number of postcript fonts are not completely installed.

Comment: @Bernard: I yesterday filed two bugs regarding Postscript fonts. You could open analogical tickets.

Comment: @Speravir: You mean asking for a gui interface to updmap? I'll do that – as soon as I recover my password.

Comment: @Bernard: Well, you could add a feature request. But I meant the incompletely installed fonts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these comments. I guess I can probably live with updating the FNDB just for new files as long as the files that are already in there update when I change them. Good to know that this is the procedure though.

Answer (score 2):

Not needing to hash the local tree in TeX Live has been the case for a few years but not always. That is true on Linux and the Mac, where TeX Live or a derivative is 'standard', and also on Windows, where both TeX Live and MiKTeX are found. It's down to Christian Schenk to define how MiKTeX works: presumably he's happier with the idea of requiring hashing for all trees. You could of course lodge a feature request.